# Distinct SUM with many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

this is a followup question os [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617616/how-to-combine-group-by-and-row-number). Since the other answers an important part(how to `SUM` by partition) i keep it accepted. But another part worries me.

How to `SUM` in a many-to-many relationship if the "left" side should counted just once.

Consider following sample data which hopefully explains my problem:

```
declare @t1 table (ID int,Price money, Name varchar(10))
declare @t2 table (ID int,Orders int,  Name varchar(10))
declare @relation  table (t1ID int,t2ID int)
insert into @t1 values(1, 200, 'AAA');
insert into @t1 values(2, 150, 'BBB');
insert into @t1 values(3, 100, 'CCC');
insert into @t2 values(1,25,'aaa');
insert into @t2 values(2,35,'bbb');
insert into @relation values(1,1);
insert into @relation values(2,1);
insert into @relation values(3,2);
-- following record will cause the "wrong" sum
insert into @relation values(2,2);

select
 T2.Name as T2Name
,T2.Orders As T2Orders
,T1Sum.Price As T1SumPrice
,T1.Price As T1HighestPrice
,T1.Name As T1HighestPrice_Name
FROM @t2 T2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Rel.t2ID
        ,Rel.t1ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By Rel.t2ID Order By Price DESC)As PriceList
        ,SUM(Price)OVER(PARTITION BY Rel.t2ID) AS Price
        FROM @t1 T1 
        INNER JOIN @relation Rel ON Rel.t1ID=T1.ID
)AS T1Sum ON  T1Sum.t2ID = T2.ID AND t1Sum.PriceList = 1
INNER JOIN @t1 T1 ON T1Sum.t1ID=T1.ID
```

Actual result:

```
T2Name  T2Orders    T1SumPrice  T1HighestPrice  T1HighestPrice_Name
aaa         25          350,00          200,00          AAA
bbb         35          250,00          150,00          BBB
```

Desired result:

```
T2Name  T2Orders    T1SumPrice  T1HighestPrice  T1HighestPrice_Name
aaa         25          350,00          200,00          AAA
bbb         35          100,00          150,00          BBB
```

Notice the difference in `T1SumPrice`. The last entry in the relation-table inserts a T1 to `bbb` that was already assigned to another T2(`aaa`), hence it's already part of `T1SumPrice` for T2-group with Name=`aaa`.

So how can i prevent counting values twice when they are already part of another group?

**Edit**:

This is the resulting query from [Nikola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665749/284240)(which is actually part of a table-valued-function). Note that i need to use the scalar-valued-functions to retrieve the values:

```
select T2.idSparePart As T2_ID
,T2.PartNumber as T2_PartNumber
,Gambio.getGoodsIn(T2.idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate) AS GoodsIn
,Gambio.getOrdered(T2.idSparePart,@FromDate,@ToDate) AS Ordered
,T1Sum.ClaimedReused As T1SumPrice_ClaimedReused
,T1Sum.Costsaving As T1SumPrice_Costsaving
,T1.Price As T1HighestPrice
,T1.idSparePart AS T1HighestPrice_ID
,T1.SparePartName As T1HighestPrice_Number
,T1.SparePartDescription As T1HighestPrice_Name
,Cat.SparePartCategoryName As T1HighestPrice_Category
FROM Gambio.SparePart T2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Rel.fiSparePart
        ,Rel.fiTabSparePart
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By Rel.fiSparePart Order By Price DESC)As PriceList
        ,SUM(Gambio.getMaterialQuantity(Rel.fiTabSparePart,NULL,NULL,@idClaimStatus,1))OVER(PARTITION BY Rel.fiSparePart) AS ClaimedReused
        ,SUM(Gambio.getCostSaving(Rel.fiTabSparePart,NULL,NULL,@idClaimStatus))OVER(PARTITION BY Rel.fiSparePart) AS Costsaving
        FROM tabSparePart T1 
        INNER JOIN 
          (select fiTabSparePart
            , fiSparePart
            from Gambio.trelSparePartClaimGroup relation
            where not exists (
                select null 
                from Gambio.trelSparePartClaimGroup rel 
                where rel.fiTabSparePart = relation.fiTabSparePart
                and rel.fiSparePart < relation.fiSparePart
            )
        )
        Rel ON Rel.fiTabSparePart=T1.idSparePart
)AS T1Sum ON  T1Sum.fiSparePart = T2.idSparePart AND t1Sum.PriceList = 1
INNER JOIN tabSparePart T1 ON T1Sum.fiTabSparePart=T1.idSparePart
INNER JOIN tabSparePartCategory AS Cat 
    ON Cat.idSparePartCategory=T1.fiSparePartCategory
```

<strike>Unfortunately it seems to skip some T1-records so that i get a wrong result</strike>

Comment: How do you want to split the values of the t1 rows across the t2 groups, where they are common members of more than one group? In the example provided, t1.ID 2 is a member of both t2.ID 1 and 2 (ie. `aaa` and `bbb`) - you appear to want its value to be assigned wholly to `aaa`, but have given no explanation of the underlying logic for doing so.

Comment: Shouldn't the Desired result have a T1Sum price of 100, not 150?

Comment: @Mark: The problem is that there is no such logic. The only thing that should be prevented is that any `T1-Price` will be counted more than once. At the end these values will be subsumed under another `Group By T1Category`. So i must ensure that i get all distinct T2 rows with the correct order-count(not summed) and one related T1 row which i then can use to group by.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Rather than arbitrarily assigning the whole value to one group, why not pro-rata the result across all applicable groups - so that the `T1SumPrice` would be 275 and 175 for groups `aaa` and `bbb` respectively?

Comment: @GarethD: Yes, you're right. Actually this is really confusing(myself included). Because the 150 is already part of `aaa` it should not be counted in `bbb`(edited). But it could also be just the opposite, part of `bbb` and removed from 'aaa'. The result would also be correct.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I assume that this would be a viable and correct approach, but actually i'm not sure how to achieve this. Keep in mind that i need the correct order-count for every `T2`. Actually things are more complicated since neither `Orders` nor `Price` are columns in these (sample-)tables but actually are scalar-valued-functions that take T1.ID/T2.ID as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do that is to filter relations so that all but first one get omitted. And if I read your example correctly, T1SumPrice should be 100,00 for bbb row because from relation you see that where t2id=1 you sum 200+150, and for t2id=2 100+150 but 150 is already spent in previous row.

```
select
 T2.Name as T2Name
,T2.Orders As T2Orders
,T1Sum.Price As T1SumPrice
,T1.Price As T1HighestPrice
,T1.Name As T1HighestPrice_Name
FROM t2 T2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Rel.t2ID
        ,Rel.t1ID
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By Rel.t2ID Order By Price DESC)As PriceList
        ,SUM(Price)OVER(PARTITION BY Rel.t2ID) AS Price
        FROM t1 T1 
        INNER JOIN 
          (select t1id, t2id
             from Relation
            where not exists (select null from relation test where test.t1id = relation.t1id
                              and test.t2id < relation.t2id)
        )
        Rel ON Rel.t1ID=T1.ID
)AS T1Sum ON  T1Sum.t2ID = T2.ID AND t1Sum.PriceList = 1
INNER JOIN t1 T1 ON T1Sum.t1ID=T1.ID
```

P.S. I was using  [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cc00/14) and had to get rid of @.

EDIT: attempt at explanation.

It works because only one of t2 relationships is permitted by subquery **rel**. I choose first id, but this depends on your use-case. As others have said, there are other options, equal or proportional distribution.

Comment: Thanks. After adding the @ again it works. But yet i'm not sure why ;) So i need some time to understand your approach and look if it's applicable.

Answer (score 2):

To pro-rata the T1 price across the SUM column but not the MAX column, try the following:

```
select
 MAX(T2.Name) as T2Name
,MAX(T2.Orders) As T2Orders
,SUM(T1Sum.ProRataPrice) As T1SumPrice
,MAX(T1Sum.Price) As T1HighestPrice
,MAX(CASE WHEN PriceList=1 THEN T1Sum.Name END) As T1HighestPrice_Name
FROM @t2 T2
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Rel.t2ID
        ,Rel.t1ID
        ,Name
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By Rel.t2ID Order By Price DESC)As PriceList
        ,Price
        ,Price / COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY Rel.t1ID) AS ProRataPrice
        FROM @t1 T1 
        INNER JOIN @relation Rel ON Rel.t1ID=T1.ID
)AS T1Sum ON  T1Sum.t2ID = T2.ID 
GROUP BY T2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

As the question isn't clear exactly what rules to implement to elimate duplicates I offer the following approach:

```
;WITH T1Sum AS
(   SELECT  Rel.t2ID,
            Rel.t1ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Rel.t2ID ORDER BY Price / Relations DESC) As PriceList,
            SUM(Price / Relations) OVER (PARTITION BY t2ID) [Price]
    FROM    @t1 T1 
            INNER JOIN 
            (   SELECT  *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1ID) [Relations]
                FROM    @Relation
            ) rel
                ON Rel.t1ID = T1.ID
)
SELECT  T2.Name as T2Name,
        T2.Orders As T2Orders,
        T1Sum.Price As T1SumPrice,
        T1.Price As T1HighestPrice,
        T1.Name As T1HighestPrice_Name
FROM    @t2 T2
        INNER JOIN T1Sum 
            ON T1Sum.t2ID = T2.ID 
            AND t1Sum.PriceList = 1
        INNER JOIN @t1 T1 
            ON T1Sum.t1ID = T1.ID
```

This will distribute the price evenly through duplicate relations so for the example it will return:

```
T2Name  T2Orders    T1SumPrice  T1HighestPrice  T1HighestPrice_Name
aaa         25          275,00          200,00          AAA
bbb         35          175,00          150,00          BBB
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I need to understand first how you're getting the average and if it's applicable on any possible assignement. But thank you already times in advance.

Comment: The query counts the number of times each T1ID appears in @Relations `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t1ID)`(line 8) It then divides the price in @t1 by the number of times t1ID appears in @Relations and considers this as the price (lines 4 & 5).